# Kubernetes parallel computing

Tags: kubernetes, cluster-computing

I want to know , Kubernetes has any parallel computing implementation ?
long time ago i used OpenHPC or OpenMosix for parallel computation cluster system .
Kubernetes can replace with this services ?
if your answer is **NO** , so What does the word cluster mean when you talk about kubernetes ?

Comment: Did you take a look at the what-is-kubernetes doc page? It has a nice section about what it can do and what it is not made for (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/what-is-kubernetes/)

Comment: @AndD Yes, but I do not understand

Comment: Do you mean something like [Parallel Processing using Expansions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/parallel-processing-expansion/) ? If no, please elaborate your question.

Comment: @PjoterS I mean , I have a  pid , but i need to cluster this process on multiple node of computers .  Use CPU and RAM of other nodes allocated in cluster . 
about 10 years ago , I did setup OpenMosix Cluster for this operation : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMosix 

Now i searching for new solutions .

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes and HPC / HTC are not yet integrated, but some attempts can be observed.

In [Kubernetes, Containers and HPC](https://www.hpcwire.com/2019/09/19/kubernetes-containers-and-hpc/) article you can find some kind of comparison between `HPC` and `Kubernetes` with similarities and differences.

> The main differences are the workload types they focus on. While HPC workload managers are focused on running distributed memory jobs and support high-throughput scenarios, Kubernetes is primarily built for orchestrating containerized microservice applications.

If you are eager to find more information, you can read some specialist books like [Seamlessly Managing HPC Workloads Through Kubernetes](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-030-59851-8_20).

Regarding second part:

> if your answer is NO , so What does the word cluster mean when you talk about kubernetes ?

You can find many definitions in the internet, however one of the easiest to understand is in [Redhat Documentation](https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/containers/what-is-a-kubernetes-cluster).

> A Kubernetes cluster is a set of node machines for running containerized applications. If you’re running Kubernetes, you’re running a cluster.
>
> At a minimum, a cluster contains a control plane and one or more compute machines, or nodes. The control plane is responsible for maintaining the desired state of the cluster, such as which applications are running and which container images they use. Nodes actually run the applications and workloads.
>
> The cluster is the heart of Kubernetes’ key advantage: the ability to schedule and run containers across a group of machines, be they physical or virtual, on premises or in the cloud. Kubernetes containers aren’t tied to individual machines. Rather, they’re abstracted across the cluster.

In addition, you can also find useful information in `Official Kubernetes Documentation` like [What is Kubernetes?](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/what-is-kubernetes/) and [Kubernetes Concepts](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/).